# Possible to query a Stripe managed account's balance?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I've gone through the docs and haven't been able to spot a way to query balance info for Stripe managed accounts. Here's the use case: a 3rd party sets up a managed account through my Stripe Connect enabled platform; I create some charge objects on their account after a few customers buy goods/services (so their balance is now positive); now they want a payout BUT I want to query their balance before issuing the transfer to ensure they're not asking for more than is in their account.

Surely I'm missing something obvious. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The response returns an object like this: `{
  "object": "balance",
  "available": [
    {
      "currency": "usd",
      "amount": 0,
      "source_types": {
        "card": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "connect_reserved": [
    {
      "currency": "usd",
      "amount": 0
    }
  ],
  "livemode": false,
  "pending": [
    {
      "currency": "usd",
      "amount": 0,
      "source_types": {
        "card": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}`


Why is the `available` and `pending` props an ARRAY? It makes no sense to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this by simply issuing a [balance retrieval call](https://stripe.com/docs/api/#retrieve_balance) while [authenticating as the connected account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header), e.g.:

`curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer {PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY}" \
   -H "Stripe-Account: {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}"`

Comment: Yup, knew it was something easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

So for Ruby, based on Ywain's answer, I figured that instead of doing [what's documented](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_balance):

```
Stripe.api_key = CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_SK
Stripe::Balance.retrieve
```

a better way, that is not documented, is to do:

```
Stripe::Balance.retrieve(stripe_account: CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID)
```

as long as the current api_key is your platform account with the managed accounts option enabled.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. How is this not documented

Comment: thanks pierrea! agreed, this needs to be added in the stripe docs

Answer (score 7):

**PHP**

```
\Stripe\Balance::retrieve([
    'stripe_account' => CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID
]);
```

**Python**

```
stripe.Balance.retrieve(
  stripe_account=CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID
)
```

**Ruby**

```
Stripe::Balance.retrieve(
  :stripe_account => CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID
)
```

**Node**

```
stripe.balance.retrieve({
  stripe_account: CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID
}, function(err, charge) {});
```